# spyder can't import opencv

Tags: python, macos, opencv, spyder

Basic problem: Spyder-Py2 2.3.3 running can't import cv (commonly known as opencv). When I attempt to "import cv" (or cv2) in a python console, the console doesn't throw an error but just becomes unresponsive. When I attempt to "import cv" in the ipython console, I get 
"It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console."
repeatedly.

Please note this is after I have added /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages to PYTHONPATH using PYTHONPATH manager. If I don't do that, the error simply says the module isn't recognized.

However, in the terminal (OSX 10.9.4) I am able to import cv and use it just fine. Spyder was installed as a .dmg and opencv was installed using Homebrew. Each has been installed and reinstalled a number of times so the order of installation is probably not the problem.

I am pretty sure that terminal and Spyder are using different python sources. In the terminal, "which python" returns /usr/local/bin/python. However, by inspecting sys.version and sys.maxint, you can see both are Python 2.7.8 and 64bit.

The only difference I can find is that in the terminal I get:
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin

Whereas in spyder I get

'2.7.8 (default, Aug 15 2014, 13:43:01) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61)]'

when i use sys.version.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450961/import-opencv-under-anaconda-fails) looks most similar, but the error message is totally different, so I think it is of a different nature.

Please. Any help would be very much appreciated.
Chris

---

Following Carlos' suggestion, I changed the default Python interpreter to /usr/local/bin/python. However, I get a new error message upon starting up Spyder. (Sorry I can't post Images for Rep reasons)

> **An error ocurred while starting the kernel**
>
> Either:
>
> 1. Your IPython frontend and kernel versions are **incompatible** or
> 2. You **don't have** IPython installed in your external interpreter.
>
> In any case, we're sorry but we can't create a console for you.

I couldn't resolve this by picking a different Python interpreter or by "pip install ipython"

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Please see the answer provided in the link below. Although it's not directly related to opencv, it describes how to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19813292/438386

Comment: I followed up on your edit and I ran into a new problem. Wasn't sure if I should make it into a new post.

Comment: Don't worry, post the error here first to see what it is about.

Answer (score 0):

Again install Anaconda and try the following code in Anaconda Prompt to install opencv

conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3

Then it will work in spyder.