# Arcpy env module is not working in Spyder

Tags: spyder, arcpy

I have gotten `arcpy` to work in `spyder` by copying the `arcpy` folder from `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5 to C:\tmp\anaconda\Lib\site-packages`.

However, when I run `from arcpy import env` I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'env' from 'arcpy' (unknown location).
```

I've gotten this all to work on another machine before, but things are not working this time around. Has anyone ran into the `arcpy` working but `env` not working in `spyder`?

I've read several posts I found online on how to get spyder to play nicely with arcpy, but have not been successful. I've also tried to change the python interpreter path to `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\python.exe`, but I get a warning saying:

```
You selected a Python 2 interpreter for the console but Spyder is running on Python 3
```

`Arcpy` will not run from `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\python.exe`. I downloaded the 32-bit and 64-bit and neither worked.

Here are links to other posts with solutions I've tried that have not worked.

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176879/importing-arcpy-in-spyder
- [Importing arcpy module into anaconda's Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795469/importing-arcpy-module-into-anacondas-spyder)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119503/getting-arcpy-to-work-with-anaconda